# Using PropertyGrid - Adding special property to PropertyGrid (e.x.: property that a user got a checkbox and a textbox)

Tags: c#, propertygrid

I read some stuff about PropertyGrid (cause I am pretty new to that control) like:

[Dynamic_Propertygrid](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tabs/Dynamic_Propertygrid.aspx)

[DynPropGrid](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tabs/DynPropGrid.aspx)

[PropertyGridInCSharp](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/PropertyGridInCSharp11302005004139AM/PropertyGridInCSharp.aspx)

But, I am still trying to get info about how to create my own `Property Type`.

Like when the user wants to enter a value then he needs to click on the checkbox and enter text in a textbox. Like two controls in the Property value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of information is spelled out in detail in [Getting the Most Out of the .NET Framework PropertyGrid Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: thanks for the link, i will try it. but there are not samples to the Custom UI (whole tutorial also). do you have any?

Comment: i found one sample that probably be enough in, but i would like to have more if there is: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/dropdownproperties.aspx